# Mouse thread in visual C++?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++

Would someone please answer my question?

Does the C++ program (written using visual studio) create a separate thread for handling mouse events? Would you please describe it concisely?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Try it Yourself and if getting some problem, Ask for help...

Comment: @ImranKhan actually, it is a simple, programming-related question with a simple answer.

Comment: How about if it is controlled by an OpenGL function like glutMotionFunc? does the glut create a separate thread?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Functions like `glutMotionFunc` are simple callbacks on the thread that created the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows, each thread that creates a window, and some that don't create any, receive a *message queue* (and remember that any application has at least one -the main- thread).

This queue is a OS structure that contains any message directed to any windows created by this thread; that includes window handling messages, timers, mouse events directed to any of these windows, keyboard events when any of these windows has the keyboard focus, system events, etc...

It is the responsibility of any thread that has a message queue to *pump* these messages periodically. This is usually done in what is called the *main loop* of the thread.

This main loop, in its simplest form is:

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
```

But it is usually much more convoluted, depending on the complexities of the program.
These two functions:

- `GetMessage(&msg)` removes one message from the queue and puts it in `msg`. The 0s mean: do not filter.
- `DispatchMessage(&msg)` handles the message, probably calling the callback function relevant to this particular message. With Window messages (mouse and keyboard included) this usually means to locate the *window class* and then call the *window function* from within.

So, answering your question: mouse messages are handled in the same thread that created the window that receives them. And it processes them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

No, the mouse events are submitted to the main UI thread/Message loop, along with keyboard and any other peripherals (and system events, and messages from other processes, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a keyboard and mouse hook in Visual C++ 2005 Check this..

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3d9bb875-8e79-4c1e-b2ef-b24503e6abbd/how-to-create-a-keyboard-and-mouse-hook-in-visual-c-2005?forum=windowssdk